# nginx root directive causing 404

Tags: nginx

I ham trying to make http://example.com serve http://example.com/home.html from /home/ubuntu/mysitedir/home.html.

I have the following conf file which successfully redirects everything to https, and proxies to uwsgi. The http->https redirection works fine, and the uwsgi proxy works, but http(s)://example.com/, http(s)://example.com/home.html, http(s)://example.com/index.html, and http(s)://example.com/index.htm are all 404

Any pointers as to what I can try?

Here is my conf file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    root /home/ubuntu/mysitedir/;
    index home.html;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example_combined.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/www.example.com.key;
    root /home/ubuntu/mysitedir/;
    index home.html;

    location /images/ads {
        alias /home/ubuntu/mysitedir/images/ads/;
    }

    location /images {
        alias /home/ubuntu/mysitedir/images/;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/ubuntu/mysitedir/static/;
    }

    location / {
        alias /home/ubuntu/mysitedir/;
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/mysitedir.sock;
   }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`location /` is the catch-all.  You could try the try_files directive like this:

```
location @wsgisite {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/mysitedir.sock;
}

location / {
    index home.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @wsgisite;
}
```

Any thing coming into the base location will first check to see if it is a file, or a directory with an index (home.html) file in it, and if not, then pass it on to the @wsgisite.

This should also make the other three location directives obselete, since nginx will be checking for the files first before passing it to the wsgi block.

Comment: Thanks miah. I tried that, with and without a root directive to no avail.  Additionally, if I place a index.htm and index.html in /home/ubuntu/mysitedir/ and /usr/share/nginx/html/, http(s)://example.com/, http(s)://example.com/home.html, http(s)://example.com/index.html, and htt(s)p://example.com/index.htm are all 404

Comment: @stubblejumper just updated with what I think will work.